# How to securely store passwords for remote services?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

How can I securely store login credentials for remote service in my web applications database?

I have to allow web applications administrator to set the username/password for remote Exchange server. I believe I cannot use hashing since I need the exact password to authenticate to the remote service. I am wondering what is the most secure way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options I believe:

- encryption by passphrase: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx
- asymetric key: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186950.aspx
- certificate: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188061.aspx
- symetric key: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx